# how to add separate links for a container and a button in it

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

[image]

I have a course container that links to the course show page. the container also has a button that allows you to enroll in a course.

But right now the enroll button doesn't work and just redirects to the course show page.

How can I get the enroll button to work while keeping the container link?

Heres my code:

```
<%= link_to course_path(course) do %>
   <div class="container hidden-xs hidden-sm hidden-lg" style="border: solid 1px black; padding: 10px; width: 70%; padding-left: 50px; padding-top: 15px; padding-bottom: 15px; margin-top: 10px; margin-bottom: 10px;">
     <div class="row col-centered">
       <div class="hidden-xs hidden-sm col-md-2 col-lg-2 index">
         <%= image_tag(course.courseimage, :size => 100) %>
       </div>
       <div class="hidden-xs hidden-sm col-md-6 col-lg-6 index" style="margin-left: 20px;">
         <h3><%= course.name %></h3>
         <p><%= course.shortdescription %></p>
       </div>
       <div class="hidden-xs hidden-sm col-md-2 col-lg-2">
         <% if course.price == 0 %>
           <%= form_for(current_user.enrolments.build) do |f| %>
             <div><%= hidden_field_tag :course_id, course.id %></div>
             <%= f.submit "Enroll", class: "btn button", style: "margin-left:10px;  padding-top: 10px; padding-bottom: 10px; font-size: 1.25em; position: relative; bottom: 50%; transform: translateY(50%); width: 130%; color: white !important;"%>
           <% end %>
         <% end %>
       </div>
     </div>
   </div>
   <% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

Rails are giving you a lot of helpers but you should remember that an effect of those is always pure HTML, sometimes with bunch of JS.
Problem you have is pure JS problem, and should be handled by JS in my opinion.
Read about event bubbling.

Answer (score 0):

You can just add a `onclick` function to your container.  This will preserve the button actions withing the container and allow you to redirect to another page when clicking inside the container but not on the button.  Something like this:

```
<div class="container hidden-xs hidden-sm hidden-lg" onclick="goToPage()" style="border: solid 1px black; padding: 10px; width: 70%; padding-left: 50px; padding-top: 15px; padding-bottom: 15px; margin-top: 10px; margin-bottom: 10px;">
 <div class="row col-centered">
   <div class="hidden-xs hidden-sm col-md-2 col-lg-2 index">
     <%= image_tag(course.courseimage, :size => 100) %>
   </div>
   <div class="hidden-xs hidden-sm col-md-6 col-lg-6 index" style="margin-left: 20px;">
     <h3><%= course.name %></h3>
     <p><%= course.shortdescription %></p>
   </div>
   <div class="hidden-xs hidden-sm col-md-2 col-lg-2">
     <% if course.price == 0 %>
       <%= form_for(current_user.enrolments.build) do |f| %>
         <div><%= hidden_field_tag :course_id, course.id %></div>
         <%= f.submit "Enroll", class: "btn button", style: "margin-left:10px;  padding-top: 10px; padding-bottom: 10px; font-size: 1.25em; position: relative; bottom: 50%; transform: translateY(50%); width: 130%; color: white !important;"%>
       <% end %>
     <% end %>
   </div>
 </div>
```

And add the following `goToPage` function to your javascript:

```
<script>
 function goToPage() {
   window.location.href = "/page/to/go/to";
   return false;
 }
</script>
```